# How can I read the blcokfile_xxxx

Tags: database, hyperledger-fabric

I tried to read the fabric produced blockfile_00000 which is at the directory /var/hyperledger/production/ledgersData/chains/chains/mychannel of the peer node.
But I can't read it through the method like:

`configtxgen -profile TwoOrgsChannel -inspectBlock ./channel-artifacts/blockfile_000000`

the error is

`[common/tools/configtxgen] main -> CRIT 004 Error on inspectBlock: Could not read block ./channel-artifacts/blockfile_000000`

using confitxlator

`configtxlator proto_decode --input ./channel-artifacts/blockfile_000000 --type common.Block`

the error is

`configtxlator: error: Error decoding: error unmarshaling: proto: can't skip unknown wire type 6 for common.Block`

I know the blockfile actually is chunk which is the collection of blocks, how to handle it?

`configtxlator version
configtxlator:
 Version: 1.2.0
 Commit SHA: f6e72eb
 Go version: go1.10
 OS/Arch: linux/amd64`

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I use docker exec command into peer node and get block through peer channel fetch . Then, read the block by configtxlator. But how to read the transaction information.

the part log is(block 6):

`"header": {
  "data_hash": "kVFRQLFjY7+6l6QsL+jOgt5ICoCUlRG4VedgmBXv/mE=",
  "number": "6",
  "previous_hash": "GQ4w7x7MQB+Jvsa3neJcTNdU7aXdKVHySA7Va3SktOs="
},`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are APIs which can be used to query blocks for any given channel:

`GetChainInfo` returns the current block height for a given channel

`GetBlockByNumber` returns individual blocks by number (you get the latest block from the GetChainInfo API work backwards from there)

All of the SDKs have methods to invoke these APIs

Comment: OK. I got it :)

Comment: According to this message from Jason Yellick, https://lists.hyperledger.org/g/fabric/message/5812, can't we decode the "blockfile_00000" using configtxlator instead of getting ledger blocks one by one and decoding everyone separately?

Answer (score 0):

configtxgen and configtxlator are meant for generating configuration transactions and translating configuration transactions into readable format respectively. Configuration Transactions include creation of channel, update anchor peers in the channel, setting the reader/writer of a channel etc. They are not meant for normal transactions which gets stored in blockfile_xxx.

You can use Hyperledger Explorer to view your block data.

Comment: Thank for your answer. But have any tool read it because I can't use Hyperledger Explorer with 1.2.0 image.

Comment: I use docker exec command into peer node and get block through peer channel fetch <block num>. Then, read the block by configtxlator. But how to read the transaction information.